# Parse nested function call string in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, graphite

I want to parse the following string (using Javascript):

```
color(alias(sumSeries(sys.mem.free.*),"memory (free)"),"#00AA88")
```

into an array of function names and arguments:

```
[["color", "#00AA88"],
 ["alias", "memory (free)"],
 ["sumSeries", ""]]
```

plus extract the innermost string

```
sys.mem.free.*
```

The string is actually the target parameter from graphite.
I don't want to write a parser myself (dealing with things like double quotes and brackets is hard to get right).
Is there a library which helps with basic parsing?

Since it's not JSON I cannot go for a JSON parser.

Comment: jsmin is the easiest js parser to customize. it's not a true ast-level deal, which is why it's simple. but, it will isolate string literals and calls, and it sounds like that's all you need.

Comment: @dandavis it's not in javascript, is it? I'm actually looking for a Javascript solution (clarified my question, realized it was only in the title)

Comment: yes, it is all js that works on other js. if you modify the return to comment-out the join() call, you will get an array of single-char elements, except for string literals, which will be longer than 1 char. if you can eliminate string literals, relatively naive string processing can parse out the nested parens.

Comment: are you referring to this? https://github.com/pkrumins/node-jsmin/blob/master/jsmin.js - indeed this looks like exactly the basic parsing code I was looking for - thanks a lot!

Comment: looks like it. i used the Marcia version back in the day, looks like it have been added to since... anyways, who cares what i meant if its what you need! glad to help.