# recursive replace with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string : pow(pow(487,2)+873,2) that I generate from a calculator I am creating. I want to trans-pile it to ((487^2) + 873)^2.

I had no problem with trans-piling pow(487,2) to 487^2 using

```
var string = `pow(487,2)`;
console.log(string.replace(/pow\((.*?),(.*?)\)/g,'$1^$2'));
```

The problem is that I don't know how to handle it recursively with pow(pow(487,2)+873,2) to become ((487^2) + 873)^2. Please help.

Comment: Regular expressions are generally not the appropriate tool for recursive patterns. I don't think JavaScript can process them. You should write a recursive descent parser.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I thought as much due to Javascript negligence of PCREs. do you have any idea of a parser i could use to achieve this.

Comment: Comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772948/parse-nested-function-call-string-in-javascript) mention [jsmin](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-jsmin/blob/master/jsmin.js)

Answer (score 0):

you can write recursive function to achieve like this

```
var string = `pow(pow(487,2)+873,2)`;
var numberOfOccurance = string.match(/pow/g).length;
const makeTranspile=(str,nooc)=>{
  const newStr=str.replace(/pow\((.*?),(.*?)\)/g,'($1)^$2');
  if(nooc>1)
  {
  return makeTranspile(newStr,nooc-1)
  }
  return newStr
}


const finalString=makeTranspile(string,numberOfOccurance);
console.log(finalString);
```